# google geocoding api returns status: 'ZERO_RESULTS' for existing ZIPs in Switzerland

Tags: google-geocoding-api

since yesterday Google geocoding api returns an empty array as result and status 'ZERO_RESULTS' for existing ZIPs in Switzerland. I've tested France, Italy and Germany as well. There everything is OK. Does anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: Can you provide examples of these postal codes, please?

Comment: Bern: 3000, 3001 Baden: 5400, 5404 (5405 works)

Comment: It sounds like a known issue. Have a look at the https://stackoverflow.com/a/51343885/5140781.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google geocoding API returns ZERO\_RESULTS for postal code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50224355/google-geocoding-api-returns-zero-results-for-postal-code)